# Network request failed at self.fetch.xhr.onload With React Native

Tags: react-native

After updating to OSX El Capitan and XCode 7.0.1, I'm getting the following error in chrome while debugging whenever I make a fetch request:

`Network request failed at self.fetch.xhr.onload`

I also now get the following warnings in XCode which may or may not be related:

`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'`

`.../node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTRootView.m:230:17: Method override for the designated initializer of the superclass '-initWithFrame:' not found`

`.../node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTViewManager.m:57:43: Unused parameter 'props'`

Answer (score -1):

Turns out to not be a ReactNative Issue. It looks like I can no longer access the local server on my mac bound to port 0.0.0.0... Not sure what that's about but that's now the problem to solve.

Comment: Turns out that it's an issue specific to apple devices and the xcode simulator. Non apple devices could connect just fine but had to update my iPhone to the latest version before being able to connect again. Assuming the next xcode update will fix.